# What are the libraries used by Pony ORM?

Tags: ponyorm

In other words, what other packages are automatically installed when I use pip install pony?

I googled this, searched stack overflow, and looked for this on the pony ORM documentation page, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays Pony doesn't require anything but standart library. But when migrations will be released, some dependecies may be added. Like: `docopt` and `contextlib2`.